# sum different values per group

Tags: perl

I have a tab-delimited file (with header line) in which I want to make the sum of some values based on the presence of data from another column.

This is how my table looks like:

```
 C1 C2  C3  C4
 a  x   e   1
 b  x       3
 c  y       1
 d  z   f   4
```

For all the identical values in C2 I want to make the sum of the corresponding values in C3.
So the new table should look like this:

```
 C1    C2    C3    C4    C5
 a     x     e     1     4
 b     x           3     4
 c     y           1     1
 d     z     f     4     4
```

So I want to keep the original structure of my table (columns C1,C2,C3,C4 and identical number of lines), but at the end I want to add another column, where in this case for line a and b the values from C4 are summed up and put in C5, since the values for C2 are identical. The values in C5 for line c&d are the same as C4, since the y&z in C2 are unique.

Can anyone help me how to do this in Perl? I suppose I should loop through the file and create a variable $sum in which by going through each line he adds up the number of C4 and then puts in C5.

Comment: Please show us your attempt at the code. One way is to make two passes over the file. First would sum up the values in C3 where C2 is the same. Second pass would read each line and append the calculated sums to each line. If file is short, you can read it into a data structure in memory.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Read the data file line by line, push every line to an array, and record the value of column 4 in a hash, using column 2 as key. When you finished, iterate that array, print its element and corresponding column 4 one by one.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my $header = <DATA>;
chomp $header;
$header = join "\t", (split /\t/, $header), 'C5';

my (%record, @lines);

while (<DATA>) {
    chomp;
    my @cols = split /\t/;
    $record{$cols[1]} += $cols[3];
    push @lines, \@cols;
}

print "$header\n";
foreach (@lines) {
    print (join "\t", (@$_, $record{$_->[1]}), "\n");
}

__DATA__
 C1 C2  C3  C4
 a  x   e   1    
 b  x       3    
 c  y       1    
 d  z   f   4
```

Comment: Thanks, it works when I try it on my example. However in my real table, which is a lot bigger, some intermediate columns (it's a table with around 200 columns) have empty values. Should I change something in the script to handle that?

Comment: @user1987607 Include some typical sample input (as you should do so in the first place), and I will try to adapt that script.

Comment: I just changed the sample input

Comment: @user1987607 What is the actual field separator? A `\t`, five spaces, or something else?

Comment: It's an excel table saved as a tab-delimited text file.

Comment: @user1987607 And those empty fields just include a space? And are those leading empty spaces in your data file?

Comment: @user1987607 Just replace those `split /\s+/` with `split /\t/` and adapt fild number properly. Answer updated.

Comment: Thanks. Seems to work. What does $record{$_->[1]} mean?

Comment: @user1987607 At there, `$_` is an array reference, and `$_->[1]` is the second element of that array, and it has been used as a key of hash `%record`. See `perlref` for further details.

Comment: Did you try it with the example that I provided? Because he's now replacing in fact the C2 with the values that are supposed to be in C5

Comment: @user1987607 In the sample input in your question, fields are NOT separated by Tab. Try to copy, paste, then run my script.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/51659/discussion-between-user1987607-and-lee-duhem)

Comment: @user1987607 It is time for me to leave office. If you have further question, leave a comment or fire another quetion.

Answer (score 1):

```
perl -lane'
  BEGIN { $, ="\t" }
  print(@F, "C4"),next if $. ==1;
  $s{ $F[1] } += $F[2];
  push @r, [ @F ];
  END {
    print @$_, $s{$_->[1]} for @r;
  }
' file
```

output

```
C1      C2      C3      C4
a       x       1       4
b       x       3       4
c       y       1       1
d       z       4       4
```

script version,

```
use strict;
use warnings;
local $, ="\t";
local $\ = "\n";

my %s;
my @r;
while (<>) {
  chomp;
  my @F = split;
  print(@F, "C4"),next if $. ==1;
  $s{ $F[1] } += $F[2];
  push @r, [ @F ];
}

print @$_, $s{$_->[1]} for @r;
```

Answer (score 0):

One simple solution would be to put the values from C3 into an array and then print each line's contents up to C3. 
For column i of C4, compare the contents of array[i-1] to array[i] and array[i+1] to array[i] i.e. compare the value of the array of the particular line with that of the previous and of the next line. If they are equal, add them, print them and move to next line.

This can be easily altered for cases where C3 is equal for more than 2 consecutive values.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind reading the file twice this can be achieved very easily using `awk` as well:

```
$ awk -v OFS='\t' 'NR==FNR{a[$2]+=$3;next}{print $1,$2,$3,$2=="C2"?"C4":a[$2]}' t.txt t.txt
C1      C2      C3      C4
a       x       1       4
b       x       3       4
c       y       1       1
d       z       4       4
```

and if you don't mind fixing the column header manually the following suffices:

```
$ awk -v OFS='\t' 'NR==FNR{a[$2]+=$3;next}{print $1,$2,$3,a[$2]}' t.txt t.txt
C1      C2      C3      0
a       x       1       4
b       x       3       4
c       y       1       1
d       z       4       4
```